# Dynamics CRM 2013contacts form_onload

Tags: dynamics-crm-2013, fetchxml

I've added an Activities subgrid to the Contacts page and want to populate the From and To fields on initial load with the user and the contact respectively. Any assistance or advice on how to accomplish this will be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

The regarding field of the activity should automatically be populated with the contact.

I would probably use JavaScript to populate the to and the from on the activities using something similar to this:

https://community.dynamics.com/crm/b/crmbusiness/archive/2012/03/21/crm-2011-setting-a-user-lookup-with-the-logged-in-user-with-javascript.aspx#.UV4PjJPYLsw

NOTE: You will have to apply JavaScript on all of the activity forms in order to get these populated for each of the activity types.